# PGFPlots axis label not moving

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Could some body please explain why I can't move the y axis label to the end of the axis like the x.
Using the following I get the below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xscale = 1.5,
                yscale = 1,
                xmin = -5, 
                xmax = 5,
                ymin = -pi / 2, 
                ymax = (pi / 2)*1.25,
                xlabel={$x$},
                ylabel={$y$},
                axis lines = center,
                samples = 1000,
                ytick = {-1.5708,-0.7853,0.7853,1.5708},
                yticklabels = {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$-\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$},
                grid style={ultra thin},
                grid=major
            ],
            \addplot[smooth,ultra thick] {rad(atan(x))} node[above left,pos=1] {$arctan \left( x \right)$}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have tried several different things but nothing has any effect.
One example I've tried is.

```
ylabel={$y$}, 
ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
```

Comment: Does it work using the most recent compatibility layer? `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}`

Comment: @Benjamin You should answer as that works. It also shows the importance of reading the console output: the package *tells you* you should probably add this.

Comment: Welcome! See comments above re. fix and re. console output, importance of. :-)

Comment: @cfr Ok, if it works I will do that. Actually I was just guessing and didn't test it.

Comment: @Benjamin I did, though ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MWE produces the following warning:

> Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode
>   (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing
>   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} into your preamble.

If you are running into problems you should always have a look at the log file. So in your case adding

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
```

solves the problem.

---

PS: It should be `\arctan` and not `arctan` as you probably don't mean the product of *a*, *r*, *c*, *t*, *a* and *n*.

Comment: Cheers worked perfectly.
So if i'm writing in backwards compatibility mode, what would be the new code to stop this problem?

Comment: And thanks for the point on the `\arctan`, makes a surprising difference.

Comment: You should not use the backwards compatibility mode unless it is absolutely necessary. Off the top of my head I don't know how to fix it there.